# Webpack @font-face relative path issue

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, font-face

I have an issue with loading the fonts using a relative path in an angular2 application.

In app.ts I have these two imports

```
import '../../../public/css/fonts.less';
import '../../../public/css/main.less';
```

Inside the fonts.less I have this @font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/public/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/public/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/public/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.svg#Montserrat-Regular') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

And this works fine. But if I try to change the path to relative e.g.

```
url('../../fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot');
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./public/css/fonts.less
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot in [...]
>   @ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./public/css/fonts.less 6:85-138
>   ERROR in ./public/css/fonts.less
>   Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot in [...]

Someone knows what can be the problem ?

P.S. I need to use relative paths for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular reason for using relative paths in webpack. You can use [webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to get rid of this necessity. Properly used aliases can resolve a lot of issues, including this one. Just specify an alias for your css and fonts directory:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src'),
    fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/fonts')
  }
}
```

and then, import the modules using aliases:

```
import '~styles/fonts.less';
import '~styles/main.less';
```

and in your font face:

```
src: url('~fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot');
```

I personally tend to avoid using relative paths in my webpack-built projects. The reason is that it is much more cleaner and readable, it prevents from problems that may arise with mixing the relative paths in different places that are dependent on each other. As a result, you have a central place where you define your paths and let the webpack resolve the relative paths for you.

Comment: Same error after implementing this:

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.eot in

Comment: make sure that your `path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/fonts')` resolves to your actual correct path. That was just an example

Comment: Of course :) But that's the correct path. I am still looking into it.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work on my side. Same error again and again. From the documentation I see that this is used for the imports. Are you sure that this will resolve also the font-face paths ?

Btw the reason I need relative paths is that we want to host the project on CDN. When doing so, we get a URL which is different per build. Without using relative paths, we get the wrong url.

Comment: Yes it should resolve urls properly in css. You can create an alias when you get the cdn url during the build.

Comment: While I'd love to report a success, I'm having the same problem like @mkolev when using your solution.